# Creating a directory in a dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, imgui

I would like to use `ImGui` within a toy app that I have created (a raytracer).  Since ImGui does not provide a simple library that can be easily consumed I have to jump through hoops to get it to work.

To avoid polluting my own `CMakeFile.txt` I thought I would pull the code and run the installer and move on with my life. But it doesn't work like that.  To keep I things tidy I decided that instead of filling my CMake files and git repo up with noise that has nothing to do with raytracing I decided to download ImGui in the `Dockerfile`, have the ignore file ignore `ext/imgui` folder so it is never checked in, compile it to a static library and then just consume it.

The `Dockerfile` was created with VSCode, so it is located within `.devcontainer` alongside `devcontainer.json`.  Into the `Dockerfile` I added the following lines

```
# get dear imgui
RUN mkdir -p ext/imgui
RUN git clone https://github.com/ocornut/imgui.git ext/imgui
```

which according to the terminal at start up did work as it is cached:

```
=> CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 2/4] RUN mkdir -p ext/im  0.0s
=> CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 3/4] RUN git clone https  0.0s
=> CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 4/4] RUN apt-get update   0.0s
```

However the folder and files are not visible within folder structure of the app.

I tried putting the `git clone` as a `CMD` and making it the last line of the `Dockerfile` but this time there was no recognisable (ie no clone occurred) output in the terminal log.

Where are my ImGui files?  What is the correct way of doing this?

My thoughts were, once I had confirmed that the folder and files were visible I would compile ImGui to a static lib and copy it a lib folder along with the headers in my tree and consume it like any other library.

Update:  I have moved on from here, forking [giladreich/cmake-imgui](https://github.com/giladreich/cmake-imgui) and adding the required backend for glfw-vulkan.  However I still need the compilation and build to occur when creating the container.